# How to show snackbar above keybord inside fragment

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have a problem. Snackbar is hidden below keybord on some devices. How to show snackbar above keybord. I found solution like this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the AndroidManifest.xml for the activity containing your snackbar but I need show snakbar inside fragment. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to hide the keyboard right before the snackbar is about to be shown like this:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
//here show your snackbar
```

Comment: @SvetaTulova good, I edited my answer. Now, the soft keyboard is hidden for the root view.

Comment: No problem, could you try this - getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() instead of getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken() ?